# Angular Post Request and Navigate to new component

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am extremely new to Angular, and am struggling to understand why my code doesn't work. I feel like its very basic functionality but I cant figure it out.

I just want to make a post request to my .NET core api to register a user and when that's finished navigate to a new component asking them to check their inbox to confirm their email.

My code is as follows

My Component:

```
  navigateToConfirm(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/confirm-email']);
  }

  Register(): void {

   this.authenticationService.register(this.userid, this.email,this.password).then(this.navigateToConfirm)}
}
```

My Service:

```
public register(userId: string, email: string, password: string): Promise<GuestUser> {
    const url = `${environment.apiHost}api/User/Register`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, { userId, email, password }).toPromise();
  }
```

My Component I'm trying to navigate to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm-email',
  templateUrl: './confirm-email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-email.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmEmailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My api endpoint :

```
[HttpPost()]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 1)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    var newUser = new GuestUser
    {
        UserName = model.UserId,
        Email = model.Email,
        Password = model.Password,
      
    };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, model.Password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var token = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser);

        byte[] tokenGeneratedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);
        var tokenEncoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(tokenGeneratedBytes);


        var link = Url.Action(nameof(VerifyEmail), "User", new { email = newUser.Email, tokenEncoded }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToString());

        MailRequest request = new MailRequest
        {
            ToEmail = newUser.Email,
            Subject = "Email Verification",
            Body = $"<h2>Thank you for registering, click the link below to verify your email! </ h2 >{link}>Verify Email</a>"
        };
        try
        {
            await MailService.SendEmailAsync(request);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
    return BadRequest(); 
}
```

app-routing-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/rou

    ter';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
    import { QuestionnaireComponent } from './questionnaire/questionnaire.component';
    import { GeneralAdviceComponent } from './general-advice/general-advice.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.gaurd';
    import { ContactTraceComponent } from './contact-trace/contact-trace.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
    import { ConfirmEmailComponent } from './confirm-email/confirm-email.component'
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'general-advice',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: GeneralAdviceComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'questions',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: QuestionnaireComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: ContactTraceComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'confirm-email',
        component: ConfirmEmailComponent
      },
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses in the `.then()` part of the promise - so you're not calling the `navigateToConfirm` method:

```
    this.authenticationService.register(this.userid, this.email,this.password)
      .then(this.navigateToConfirm())}
```

Comment: No still doesn't work.. thank you for responding though

Comment: Sorry, not used to promises. Try using .then(() => this.navigateToConfirm()).

Comment: No still not navigating to my other component my endpoint works fine and sends out the email I've updated the answer to show my other component and the api

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks normal but maybe the register request is failing. You should consider to use **catch()** after **then()** and can be sure the request succeeded.

What i mean is:

```
this.authenticationService.register(payload)
    .then(this.navigateToConfirm)
    .catch(console.log)
```

Update:

You can try to use `router.navigateByUrl(path)` and update your method as follows:

```
navigateToConfirm(): void {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('confirm-email');
}
```

Comment: My request is working it sends the email, I think my issue is with my return type of the api, this is all quite new to me so I think I'm doing something wrong, I've updated my question to show the endpoint and the component I'm trying to navigate to. Maybe you can spot something I'm doing wrong there. Thanks for the response

Comment: Does your navigateToConfirm method execute?

Comment: No it is found but the code inside doesn't execute?

Comment: If the navigateToConfirm method executed but code inside doesn't execute then problem is about the navigation. Can you add AppRoutingModule of page you want to navigate to?

Comment: I've edited my question to include app-routing-module

Comment: I'm updating my answer due to your app-routing-module.

Comment: Are you sure your navigateToConfirm method executed? Did you use console.log inside of navigateToConfirm?

Comment: No it executed my code looks exactly like it does in my question above besides the navigatebyurl from your answer